# Unable to retrieve resource through getIdentifier

Tags: java, android

I have following element in my XML

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kernelb11"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/matrixBoxWidthHeight"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewb"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/marginOne"
        android:background="@color/white1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:text="5" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

And i am trying to retreive its value in code like:

```
String name = "kernelb11";
int a = this.getResources().getIdentifier(name, null, null); // 
String as = (String) this.getResources().getText(a);
```

but at `getIdentifier` is returning me just '0' can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
int a = this.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "id", getPackageName());
```

As others pointed out this is not the best way to do it (although, should work).
Normally, you should use `findViewById` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can only `null` the last two parameters if you specify them in the `name` parameter, like:

```
String name = "my.package.name:id/kernelb11";
```

If you want to just use the name, you need to do it like this:

```
getIdentifier(name, "id", "my.package.name")
```

([Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29))

---

**However**, this probably won't do what you want. To get a string from an EditText, you should normally do something like this:

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kernellb11);
String as = et.getText().toString();
```